# Use React Context With Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to store my array with local storage, but I am not sure how to do it. Also, how would I make it so that with each update in the state, the local storage gets updated at the same time?

Current Code:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const NoteContext = createContext();

export const NoteProvider = props => {

    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'e', selected:false},
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
    
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
        
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
    
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
    
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false},
            {id:uuidv4(), message:'asdfasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',title:'New Note', selected:false}
    
    ])
    return (
        <NoteContext.Provider value={[notes, setNotes]}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the data from state to `localStorage` using a `useEffect` hook?

Comment: I know i need to use the useEffect hook, I just dont know how to implement it

Comment: I think `recoil-js` suits your needs. It uses `context` api alongside `local-storage`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can initialize your state from `localStorage` as well as propagate changes to it using `useEffect`.

```js
function getInitialState() {
  const notes = localStorage.getItem('notes')
  return notes ? JSON.parse(notes) : []
}

export const NoteProvider = props => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(getInitialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes))
  }, [notes])
}
```

Comment: how would i set initial state?

Comment: Just update the `getInitialState` function to include default state if the local storage item is missing.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the localStorage on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Local storage acts like a map, with key value pairs. In order to set an array into local storage, you'll first have to convert it to json.

```
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes);
```

To retrieve the items,

```
const storedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
```

Lastly, you can create a function to update your state and your storage

```
const updateStorageAndState = (newState) => {
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newState));
  setNotes(newState);
}
```