# What is the ideal way of restoring state from client session storage in Nextjs before rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am handling a situation that the user refresh the webpage by pressing F5, therefore I have to restore the state from client session storage to the useState hook.

At first, I try to perform this with useEffect  hook, due to the useEffect and the rendering are process concurrently, therefore it has a flashing moment which rendering with the not updated state.

```
"use client"

import { createContext,useState } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

const ThemeProvider = ({children})=>{
const [theme, setTheme] = useState({foo:'bar'})

return (
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, setTheme}}>
    {children}
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
)
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

```
'use client';

import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "@/_contexts/ThemeContext";

const Item = ()=>{
const {theme, setTheme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

useEffect(()=>{
  const sessionState = sessionStorage.getItem('storedState');
  setTheme(sessionState);
},[])

const onClickHandler =()=>{
  sessionStorage.setItem('storedState', 'haha');
}

return <div>
  <div>
    {JSON.stringify(theme)}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>set session value</button>
    </div>
</div>

}

export default Item;
```

And I try to solve it with a pending state:

```
'use client';

import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "@/_contexts/ThemeContext";

const Item = ()=>{
const {theme, setTheme} = useContext(ThemeContext);
const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

useEffect(()=>{
  setPending(true);
  const sessionState = sessionStorage.getItem('storedState');
  setTheme(sessionState);
  setPending(false);
},[])

const onClickHandler =()=>{
  sessionStorage.setItem('storedState', 'haha');
}

return <div>
  {!pending && <>
  <div>
    {JSON.stringify(theme)}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>set session value</button>
    </div>
  </>
}
</div>

}

export default Item;
```

It did what I want to prevent the ui show up before the restore completed.

But I'm just wondering is it a ideal way in nextjs? Or I can handle the pending with other stuff like something boundary or method?

Comment: Does this answer help: ["initialize your state from localStorage"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71451614/7556457) ? But also: Depending on the use case, the `pending` state might be fine. Maybe you could better make the display dependent on the availability of the data, instead of an extra `pending` state.